# How to publish Jest Test Results in Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have test report from Jest.
I want show the result in Jenkins.

I tried use jest-junit but I failed to publish the junit xml in Jenkins

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-jenkins-reporter?

Comment: @shmit jest-jenkins-reporter creates an XML file. What must one do on the Jenkins side to make the report show up in a job result?

Comment: You should be able to use some Jenkins plugin to parse that xml and show the report. An example that may be worth trying is https://plugins.jenkins.io/summary_report/.  I do not have the setup currently on my machine to try it myself else would have shared more concrete information.

Answer (score 13):

based on the comments, the solution I implemented was:

add `jest-junit` to your package.json:

```
yarn add --dev jest-junit
```

and in your jest config, add the following entry:

```json
{
  "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit"
}
```

For me that generates a `junit.xml` file when the tests are run. Then for Jenkins to collect them  you use the `junit` plugin in the post stage:

```
junit checksName: 'Jest Tests', testResults: 'junit.xml'
```

or if you're using 'scripted' instead of 'declarative' syntax, can use a try/finally:

```
try {
    sh "jest --ci"
} finally {
    junit checksName: 'Jest Tests', testResults: 'junit.xml'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, worked perfectly. I have an additional question though. When viewing the test results page, the tests are in "(root)" folder. I do not like this and I would prefer to have it in a folder of my own naming. Can I configure this somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this would be in the jest or jest-junit settings. It's usually something at the reporting level where you can change the source. (I did a quick look but didn't find it, so I don't have an answer)

Comment: For the specific "(root)" problem here is the answer https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter/issues/95#issuecomment-1504508896